# What does "post" mean in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> when your butler warns you to be wary of the grave risks you would be taking, you force your wary butler to resign from his **post**.

Two possible meaning: point of view and occupation as a butler.

I searched up post and could only find its definitions being an object, metal usually.

Comment: Why do you think it could mean point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**post**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/post_1)

> a place where a soldier or guard must remain in order to do their job
>
> *He was at his post at the gate from midnight until 3:00 a.m.*

As hinted at above, there's a certain military connotation, but it can be used as a simple synonym for *job/assigned position*.

[***posting***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/posting) is probably more common.

> assignment to a post, command, or particular location, especially in a military or governmental capacity.

Comment: So no point of view?

Comment: @Doeser No.  Doesn't mean that in the quote provided. I can see how you might think the butler would need to cede/compromise/change his opinions on the matter, but what they're saying is that he'd be forced to resign his job.

Answer (score 0):

POST, amongst others,also means assigned station or appointmented position. So,your expression has nothing wrong in it.